# How can I save a copy of Properties.Settings.Default to a variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I have a **"Restore Defaults"** button in an options dialog and want to restore the values that are affected in this form only and not the whole Properties.Settings.Default

So I tried:

```
var backup = Properties.Settings.Default;
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
overwriteControls();
Properties.Settings.Default = backup;
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work since backup seems to change at `Reload()`, too? Why and how would I do this correctly?

Comment: You are only saving a reference to the settings object, not a copy of it. Hence, Reload *will* update the one and only object that is available and you can see that through both varaibles.

Comment: So this is a pointer to Properties.Settings.Default or what? Actually I didn't used the synthax for a pointer ... this really confuses me ... how would I save a copy of it?

Comment: .NET uses the concept of "Reference Types" and "Value Types". Class instances are "Reference Types" and variables point to them. It's a pointer but managed by the runtime. In order to copy an object, it has to support some form of "cloning" - The http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx IClonable interface is used for that. However, the settings objects don't implement it and I have no idea how to solve this without further research which is why I didn't propose this as an answer, just pointing out where and why your code failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Settings class uses a singleton pattern, meaning their can only ever be one instance of the settings at any one time. So making a copy of that instance will always refer to the same instance.

In theory, you could iterate over each of the properties in the Settings class using reflection and extract the values like this:

```
        var propertyMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // backup properties
        foreach (var propertyInfo in Properties.Settings.Default.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.CanWrite && propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserScopedSettingAttribute), false).Any())
            {
                var name = propertyInfo.Name;
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(Properties.Settings.Default, null);
                propertyMap.Add(name, value);
            }
        }

        // restore properties
        foreach (var propertyInfo in Properties.Settings.Default.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.CanWrite && propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserScopedSettingAttribute), false).Any())
            {
                var value = propertyMap[propertyInfo.Name];
                propertyInfo.SetValue(Properties.Settings.Default, value, null);                    
            }
        }
```

Although, it's a bit icky, and might need some work if your settings are complex. You might want to rethink your strategy. Rather than restoring the values to defaults, you could only commit the values once the OK button is pressed. Either way, I think you are going to need to copy each of the values to some temporary location on a property by property basis.

Comment: Only commiting the values when the OK button is pressed is exactly what I want to do. But I need a simple way to reset the controls to default, when **"Restore Defaults"** is pressed. So I thought I backup the settings, then do `Reload()`, reset the controls with that values and then restore the backup. But maybe its better to use something like `checkBox1.Checked = bool.Parse((string)settings.Properties["setting1"].DefaultValue);` But that looks kind of awful :-/

Comment: I used your example for unit testing where I didn't want the unit test to overwrite existing settings.