# Use Settings DefaultValue without knowing its Type beforehand

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, application-settings

**The short version**

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
settings["name1"] = Settings.Default.Properties["name1"].DefaultValue;
```

fails. It seems that `DefaultValue` is always just a `string`.

**The long version**

I'm trying to create an application "Reset Settings" button, but I can't use the built-in `Reset` method because I don't want it committed until a user's OK. So I'm trying to "Clone" the Settings using the following code:

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
foreach (SettingsProperty p in Settings.Default.Properties)
    settings[p.Name] = Settings.Default.Properties[p.Name].DefaultValue;
return settings;
```

but I get a "The settings property 'Setting1' is of a non-compatible type." error.
Though when I do a simple Clone using this code:

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
foreach (SettingsProperty p in input.Properties)
    settings[p.Name] = input[p.Name];//Notice the absence of "Properties" after "input".
return settings;
```

it works fine.

So how do I "Clone" the default `Settings`?

Comment: What is the type of `input`? I think there needs to be some more code posted here. How can you construct a `Settings settings = new Settings()` and then access elements in it with `settings[p.Name]`? What is a `Settings` and what happens in the default constructor?

Comment: @Choc13 `Settings`. Just like `Settings.Default`.

Comment: The only possibility for the type mismatch must be due to the fact that `Settings.Default.Properties[p.Name].DefaultValue` is of a different type to `input[p.Name]`. What is the type of `DefaultValue`?

Comment: @Choc13 They are both `object`s. Try it and see. But the actual property is a `Color`.

Comment: See [How can I save a copy of Properties.Settings.Default to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15423674/719186)